# What do you refer to an alternation between 3 things? or the like

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary, sentence-patterns

For example: 1-1-2-1-1-2-1-1-2 ( pattern of 1-1-2 repeated) and another pattern with more than 3 units and more complex and so forth.

I would normally call this: 1-2-1-2-1-2 an alternation between 1 and 2 (if you have other interesting ways to address it, please share).

Because I have to refer to '1-2-1-2-1-2' in one sentence and '1-1-2-1-1-2-1-1-2' in the next. I'm trying to use a word to connect the two, alternation in 2 and alternation in 3 for example, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'd call it a **cyclical pattern**

Comment: Are you looking for a word describing exactly three parts of just more than two?

Comment: i guess i'm curious to know both.

Comment: If you really wanted to include the word *alternation* in your description of the pattern ***1-1-2-1-1-2-1-1-2*** then rather than saying it "repeats" the element ***1-1-2***, you could say it alternates between ***1-1*** and ***2***. Or indeed, between ***1*** and ***1-2***. Or forget alternation, and just say one sequence contains repeated ***pairs***, whereas the other contains repeated ***triplets***.

Comment: doesn't have to be alternation, really. but the emphasis is on the number. the first pattern, it changes 2 times and repeats. the second. it changes 3 times and repeats. i try to find a noun/phrase that would use for both sentence to connect them( to sound more interesting). pattern of 2, and pattern of 3. maybe? thanks

Comment: *cyclical*, *repeating*, or *periodic* pattern, with *period* 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think the commonest way to describe movement through a cyclical pattern of more than 2 elements would be "rotation". Your example is a bit non-standard, because there are really only 2 elements, but the way in which they repeat is a triplet. Still, I think the word "rotation" would carry the right meaning. The pattern is a 3-step rotation among the elements 1-1-2.